# Swap columns value in output based on certain condition using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table say "Temp" with columns "From", "To" and "Symbol"
i want to swap the value of column "To" into column "From" based on value in column "Symbol"..
For Example

```
Temp      From        To        Symbol
        -1000        -24858       <
         2000         50000       ><
         4000         8000        >
```

All i want is to swap value of "To" into "From" and value of "From" into "To" where value of "Symbol" is "<", rest will remain same. **And this output should be result of select query.**

so output will be like:

```
Temp      From        To        Symbol
        -24858       -1000        <
         2000         50000       ><
         4000         8000        >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select (Case when symbol='<'
then [to] 
else [from] end)as [from],(Case when symbol='<'
then [from] 
else [to] end)as [to] from temp
```

here is [SQL FIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f288e/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
update tablename
SET [to]= case WHEN symbol='<' THEN [from] ELSE [to] END,
[from]=case WHEN symbol='<' THEN [to] ELSE [from] END
```